# triggering beforeRemove, afterAdd handlers in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I am having some problems getting KnockoutJs beforeRemove and afterAdd handlers to fire.

This is the relevant code fragment

```
function viewModel(list) {
    var self = this;

    this.items = ko.observableArray(list);

    this.removeItem = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    }

    this.removeFirst = function() {
        self.removeItem(self.items()[0]);
    };

    this.onRemove = function(elements) {
        console.log("Updating");
        $(elements).addClass('transition-out');
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(items));
```

And this markup

```
<button data-bind="click: removeFirst">Remove first</button>
<ul data-bind='foreach: items, beforeRemove: onRemove'>
    <li data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.removeItem"></li>
</ul>
```

I am seeing list updates but the `onRemove` handler is never fired.

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/c6FvB/) to illustrate the problem.

Thanks,

Gene

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The syntax that you want to use looks like:

```
data-bind='foreach: { data: items, beforeRemove: onRemove }'
```

`beforeRemove` is an option that is accepted by the `foreach` (and ultimately the `template`) binding.  It was being treated as a separate binding in the way that you were specifying it.  If a binding does not exist, then it is ignored (some binding are accessed via allBindingsAccessor, so KO wouldn't know that and doesn't throw an error).

Also, the function will get called once for each node in your "template".  In your case it will be a text node, the `li`, and another text node.  If you want to ignore the text nodes, then check that the element's (first argument) nodeType is 1.

Comment: thanks! I missed that the scope of `beforeRemove` should be the value of `foreach`; makes sense of course!

Comment: It doesn't look like this is even explained on the knockoutjs live tutorial page for animated transitions.  I'm glad I found this answer!  Thanks Niemeyer.